# Panel Form Toggle Issue: Opening and Closing Form on Button Click

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I am trying to create a panel containing a form that should open and close with the help of a button. I am new to C# programming, so I believe I might be making a mistake in my code.

Here's my code:

```
 public frmteacherpanel()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            btnClassOps.Click += btnClassOps_Click;

        }
        
        private void btnClassOps_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            if (pnlDesktopPanel.Controls.Count != 0)
            {
                pnlDesktopPanel.Controls.Clear();
            }
            else
            {
                frmClassOps frmClassOperations = new frmClassOps() { TopLevel = false, TopMost = true };
                frmClassOperations.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
                frmClassOperations.Size = pnlDesktopPanel.Size;
                pnlDesktopPanel.Controls.Add(frmClassOperations);
                frmClassOperations.Show();
            }
```

I am trying to create a panel containing a form that should open and close with the help of a button

Answer (score 0):

```
            frmClassOps frmClassOperations = new frmClassOps() { TopLevel = false, TopMost = true };
            frmClassOperations.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            frmClassOperations.Size = pnlDesktopPanel.Size;
            pnlDesktopPanel.Controls.Add(frmClassOperations);

            frmClassOperations.Parent = pnlDesktopPanel; // just add this line

            frmClassOperations.Show();
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?